# Display html form on same jsp page

Tags: jsp

In image mentioned, if I click "add new button" then my html form should be on same page(gold.jsp page).but it goes another jsp page(additem.jsp as mentioned in javascript code here), how can I display it on gold.jsp page itself, it goes additem.jsp here.
[image]

This is my gold.jsp page coding, here I used javascript inside jsp.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert gold</title>
</head>

<style type = "text/css">
body
{
background-color:black;
}
p
{
color:yellow;
}

button
{
background-color:yellow;

}


p
{
color:yellow;
}
</style>
<script type ="text/javascript">
function onsubmitform()
{
    if(document.pressed == "insert")
        {

        document.myform.action = "additem.jsp";


        }

    else if(document.pressed == "addstock")
    {

    document.myform.action = "display.jsp";
    }

    }









</script>
<body>
<hr/>

<img src = "C:\Users\ms trapti\workspace\jewellery\WebContent\images\images2.jpg"   width = "50px" height = "50px" vspace = "5px"/>
<center><img src = "E:\jewellery 18-dec\18decjewry\jewellerynew\WebContent\images\untitled2.png" alt = "gold" width = "60px" height = "60px"></img></center>
<p><i>Trapti jewellery</i></p>
<center><p> Gold Management System</p></center><br/>

<div style = "position:fixed;  left: 300px; bottom: 130px;" >
<p>Tray No:<select>
<option value ></option>
</p>
</select>
</div>

<table>

<form name = "myform" onsubmit = "return onsubmitform();">
<button type = "submit" name = "operation" onclick = "document.pressed = this.value" value = "addstock">Add new Stock</button><br/><br/>



<button type = "submit" name = "operation" onclick = "document.pressed = this.value" value = "insert">Add new Item</button><br/><br/>
<button type = "submit" name = "operation" onclick = "document.pressed = this.value" value = "insert">Delete Item</button><br/><br/>



<button type = "submit" name = "operation" onclick = "document.pressed = this.value" value = "update">Purchase</button><br/><br/>
<button type = "submit">Sales</button><br/><br/>

</form>
</table>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more ? Is it throwing 404 error, you page doesn't send data?, etc.

Comment: In my case, it works perfect, my problem is , I want html form, in same page means (image mentioned above , in that page, in gold.jsp page).means I wrote html code in additem.jsp, so when I click "add new item" it goes on additem.jsp because I give it in javascript code, I want , how to write html code(which I write in additem,jsp) in gold.jsp itself and give the path of gold.jsp , so that when I click "add new item", the html form shows in gold.jsp page itself rather it goes additem.jsp?

Comment: uhmm, I think I understand you now. I believe that you want to click in someone of those links at left area, then, they render/load some page in your center page, is it ? So I believe you will need made it through ajax requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple AJAX requests to load partial JSP pages from your server:

```
<script>

    // jQuery will bind a click function for your A tag with #menu-link-one id.
    $("#menu-link-one").click(function(){
    // Here you have to inform the target of your ajax request (your server). 
    var uri = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/path/for/your/desired.jsp";

    var uriForServlets = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/some-mapped-servlet/"

    var args= {};

    $.post(uri, args, function(data){
         // This will put the ajax response inside your div with #main-area id.
         $("#main-area).html(data);
    });
    });

</script>
```

Is it what you looking for ?

Comment: ok so , I read Ajax's one or two tutorials, but this code does not clear to me because I do not know much about ajax, I think ajax is used with php also, should I go for ajax with java tutorials, or can you give me right link so that I can understand the ajax with java tutorial..

Comment: Ok. AJAX is used by a lot of languages to rich client side applications, what change for you is URI, I'll edit my answer.